# Bypass "Perform the following action(s)" in KeyCloak?

Tags: python, keycloak

Using KeyCloak as the identity management backend, I'd like a newly registered user to receive a custom email with a verification code to a designated domain (not KeyCloak's default link).

Currently, KeyCloak will send an email linking to a "perform the following action" KeyCloak page; e.g.:

`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test_webapp/login-actions/action-token?key=eyJhb...`

Following this link, the KeyCloak-served page asks to 'proceed to email verification', using yet another link to:

`http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/<myrealm>/login-actions/required-action?execution=VERIFY_EMAIL&client_id=account&tab_id=Vu4BAcuG2X1`

This auth / verification dance seems cumbersome and exposes KeyCloak to users directly - I'd like the entire user authentication flow (from registration onwards) to be handled by my backend, not KeyCloak. Is there a way to send a custom email with some token to allow verifying the user?

A sample flow would be:

1. User registers on mysite.com's `/register` path and is redirected to a 'check your email page'
2. mysite.com's backend registers a new user via KeyCloak's ReST API, with "emailVerified=False".
3. User receives a **[custom] email** to verify their email address, e.g. email content would be: `<a href="mysite.com/verify-email?code=<some_code">verify</a>`
4. mysite.com's backend exchanges `<some_code>` with KeyCloak's ReST API to verify this user's email and [if verification ok] KeyCloak is to change emailVerified to True.

Is this possible with KeyCloak?

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: I'm now using FusionAuth where this workflow (and IIRC some other use cases) is easily implemented.

Comment: Anyone had success to resolve this issue ?